# Find the first element with a certain class/tag name after another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a web page that looks like this:

```
<h1 id="a">A</h1>
contents
<p class="paragraph">stuff</p>
more contents

<h1 id="b">B</h1>
contents
<p class="paragraph">stuff I need</p>
more contents

<h1 id="c">C</h1>
contents
<p class="paragraph">stuff</p>
more contents

et cetera
```

How can I select the `<p class="paragraph">` tag after the heading with `id="b"` (with contents "stuff I need")?

I have thought about locating the index of `<h1 id="b">B</h1>` in `$("h1")` and then accessing that index in `$("p.paragraph")`, but that won't work in my specific case.

EDIT: a better example: https://jsfiddle.net/n7zstmw8/

Comment: Just for correctness - I would suggest not using h1's so liberally - the idea of a <h1> heading is that it is the single most important heading on the page. You can have multiple h1s if each is within its own section - so that it becomes the most important heading in that section - but with your existing code structure you have would been better if you have a single h1 (eg <h1>Stuff<//h1>) and then you would have a <h2></h2> for each of the three options.

Comment: @gavgrif I absolutely agree with you on this. This is just a model of what my page looks like. Actually, it's not even my page, but from another website that I'm trying to scrape (otherwise I'd have assigned more classes and ids so that this question would not have come up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The select is:

```
$('#b + .paragraph')
```

> [Next Adjacent Selector (“prev + next”)](https://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/): Selects all next elements matching "next" that are immediately preceded by a sibling "prev".

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  console.log($('#b + .paragraph').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="a">A</h1>
contents
<p class="paragraph">stuff</p>
more contents

<h1 id="b">B</h1>
contents
<p class="paragraph">stuff I need</p>
more contents

<h1 id="c">C</h1>
contents
<p class="paragraph">stuff</p>
more contents
```

If the next element is not adjacent you may use nextAll:

```js
$(function () {
  console.log($('#b').nextAll('.paragraph:first').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="a">A</h1>
<span class="inbetween">In between stuff</span>
<p class="paragraph">stuff</p>
<span class="inbetween">In between stuff</span>

<h1 id="b">B</h1>
<span class="inbetween">In between stuff</span>
<div class="moreinbetween">
    More stuff
</div>
<p class="paragraph">stuff I need</p>
<span class="inbetween">In between stuff</span>

<h1 id="c">C</h1>
<span class="inbetween">In between stuff</span>
<p class="paragraph">stuff</p>
<span class="inbetween">In between stuff</span>
```

Comment: "that are immediately preceded" but what if I have tags in between the `<h1>` and the `<p>` (I do)?